# Serialize Treeview to JSON and Deserialize back to Treeview

Tags: c#, .net, json

I need to serialize a Treeview node to JSON format and deserialize back to a Treeview.

I have got a custom SubNode class as shown below

```
Class SubNode: TreeNode
{
    dynamic obj;
}
```

So when a tree node is created, it will also have a complex object in every node as shown below.

```
SubNode sub = new SubNode();
sub.obj.property = "Value1"
sub.obj.Complex.Prooerty = "Value2"
```

so on....

Could you please let me know how do we achieve this? Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at existing libraries out there, the famous one is using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). You can look at the examples on how to do it.

**Serializing an object**

```
public class Account
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}

Account account = new Account
 {
     Email = "james@example.com",
     Active = true,
     CreatedDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 20, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
     Roles = new List<string>
     {
         "User",
         "Admin"
    }
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account, Formatting.Indented);
// {
//   "Email": "james@example.com",
//   "Active": true,
//   "CreatedDate": "2013-01-20T00:00:00Z",
//   "Roles": [
//     "User",
//     "Admin"
//   ]
// }

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Deserializing an object**

```
string json = @"{
   'Email': 'james@example.com',
   'Active': true,
   'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
   'Roles': [
     'User',
     'Admin'
   ]
 }";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

Comment: I have the same question. But this is a Account class, not a TreeNode class? Json dont work out of the box with hierarchical structures. It only write and read the first node.